# How can I check data has been inserted successfully?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two insert statements. The second one will be executed only after successful execution of first one. What I would like to do is:

```
$sqlone="Insert into .....";
$sqltwo="Insert into.....";

If (mysql_query($sqlone))
{
   If (mysql_query($sqltwo))
   {
      Show message Data inserted in both tables.
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error using the above code? It should work just fine. `mysql_query()` returns `TRUE` on success and `FALSE` on error for inserts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$query1 = '...';
$query2 = '...';
$query3 = '...';
if(mysql_query($query1)) {
     if(mysql_query($query2)) {
          if(mysql_query($query3)) {
              echo "success";
          }
          else { echo "error"; }
     }
     else { echo "error"; }
}
else { echo "error"; }
```

Comment: Not only did you reiterate what 3 people have already said, you have a typo. `$query3` is opened with a double quote and closed with a single.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for transactions.

A bit of googling gave me [some](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Using-Transactions-with-MySQL-4.0-and-PHP/) [info](http://webdevology.com/2009/02/18/mysql-based-transactions-using-php5/) on [database transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) in PHP - hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax looks like it works, as...

`For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.`

https://www.php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For other type of SQL statements,
>   INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success
>   or FALSE on error.

So as far as I can see there is no problem with what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the DB transaction as well in which commit of one insert will execute the second insert statement..